# How to sort records in repeat control

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm new to xpages, basically I'm learning everything right now. 
My question: I have a xpage that has a records shown by repeat control that takes data from a view. I want to sort that records for example by A to Z or price. I want to choose sorting rule from a combobox (something that look similiar to online stores) How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Show us your existing code for your repeat control (especially the value part which is input to your repeat) and describe what you have tried so far. See this for a reference on how to ask a question in order to get the best answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem is that I haven't tried anything because I just simply don't know where should I start or if it is possible to sort records from repeat control.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Change the order of your values, then the displayed data are sorted like you want themt to be sorted.

Comment: StackOverflow is the wrong place to come for problems where you "simply don't know where to start".

Comment: Have a look at  http://datatables.net

Comment: Example of datatables used with XPages can be found here:
http://notesx.net/datatables.nsf/index.xsp
More info on this demo can be found here:
https://oliverbusse.notesx.net/hp.nsf/blogpost.xsp?documentId=D5E (Kuddos to Oliver Busse)